# script to read certain key words in a document

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have a list of 50 folders. Inside every folder I have a text file contain key words and this file has the same name in all the folders but it has different values.
How can a script read a certain key words inside those text files and save (collect)  those result in a new file?

```
    folder A 
       text.file (inside it key words let us say Abc=1 Def=2 Ghi=3 )
    folder b
       text.file(inside it key words let us say Abc=5 Def=1 Ghi=4 )
    folder c
       text.file(inside it key words let us say Abc=11 Def=12 Ghi=32 )
    folder d
       text.file(inside it key words let us say Abc=11 Def=27 Ghi=34 )
    folder e
       text.file(inside it key words let us say Abc=16 Def=12 Ghi=22 )
    folder f
       text.file(inside it key words let us say Abc=3 Def=2 Ghi=1)
    .
    .
    .
    .
    folder N
```

The key words are sorted in the text file as the following (and this sort for the key words is the same in all the files included in the 50 folder)

```
    Abc= value
    Def= value
    Ghi= value
```

For example: I need the script to read the key word "Abc" in all the files and save the output (i.e. collect the values for the key word "Abc" separably in a new file) as a text file contain just the "Abc" values from all the folders as the following:

```
Abc=1
Abc=5
Abc=11
Abc=11
Abc=16
Abc=3
```

Comment: Are `Abc=1`, `def=2`, etc. on the same line with spaces in between, or on separate lines, or something else? If they're on separate lines, can there be initial whitespace before the keywords? Are the keywords case-insensitive (you've used `Abc` in some places and `abc` in others)?

Comment: @MJA: Where did you mention this?

Comment: My bad!! I will update the question. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: @Gilles. thanks. they are as I mentioned before. They are sorted as a column in the text file (separate lines). yes the keywords are case sensitive (Sorry for the typos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all key words are sorted in the text.file as the following (and this sort for the key words is the same in all the files included in the 50 folder)

```
Abc= value
Def= value
Ghi= value
```

Then you can read each first line `head -n 1 filename` of them into for loop and write it in new file like below:

```bsh
$ for file in ~/Parent_dir/Folder*/*; do  head -n 1 $file; done
 Abc=1
 Abc=5
 Abc=11
 Abc=11
 Abc=16
 Abc=3
```

Your script will be look like above:

```bsh
for file in ~/Parent_dir/Folder*/*; do
    head -n 1 $file;
done > newfile
```

Comment: Can I use two for loops here. For example I will include the parent folders names in a text file then I will use for i in txt file do; the second for loop?

Comment: I want to do it like parent_dir/${i} and i is one of my list of folder names included in a text file

Comment: @MJA Yes you can but why not one for loop?

Comment: can I say for file in and i in the text file.

Comment: @MJA [here it is](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8823427/) ;)

Comment: @KasiysA. You are great. Thank you!. Just one more question. head -n 1 will read the first line in the file. If I want the fifth line can I write head -n 5

Comment: @MJA No with that command you will read first 5 lines of file. If you want to read 5th line, `sed` command is useful. you can use `sed 'NUMq;d' filename`. Where NUM is the number of line you want to read. ;) If you have a new question, please open it as new one. Thanks and welcome
`